# Computing these multiplicities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to use some Algebraic Geometry techniques to check my understanding on them. I'm using the most stupid of all the examples: trying to compute the multiplicities of the intersections of the curves $C_1$ given by $y=x^2$ and $C_2$ given by $y=-x^3$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I know (though I might be wrong) that the points of intersections are $P_1=(0,0)$ and $P_2=(-1,1)$. Also, the multiplicities of these intersections (using the fact that both the curves are given, respectly, by the same equation around each intersection point) are
$$
i(C_1,C_2,P_1)=\dim_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_{\langle x,y\rangle}/(y-x^2,y-x^3)
$$

where $\mathcal{O}_{\langle x,y\rangle}$ stands for the localization of the local ring on the ideal $\langle x,y\rangle$ that corresponds to the point $P_1$.

I'm not sure if this is correct at all. I've seen some people using that $\mathcal{O}_{\langle x,y\rangle} \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, yet still I can't see how I would use this to calculate the multiplicity that I need.

I editted it. I believe there is some way to simplify the ideal $(y-x^2,y-x^3)$ so the calculation of the dimensions gets straightfoward?

Comment: You're adding the equations together for no apparent reason.  You want to compute using the ideal they both generate.  Also, $y-x^3 \neq y+x^3$.

Comment: Damn, that's right, I was thinking about something else. Lemme correct that.

Comment: For your own good avoid "people  using that $\mathcal{O}_{\langle x,y\rangle} \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak m\subset A$ is a maximal ideal in a ring $A$ then for any ideal $I\subset \mathfrak m$
we have an isomorphism $A_\mathfrak m/I_\mathfrak m\cong (A/I)_\mathfrak m$.
So in your case:
 $\mathcal{O}_{\langle x,y\rangle}/(y-x^2,y-x^3)=( \mathbb C[x,y]/(y-x^2,y-x^3))_{(x,y)}=( \mathbb C[x]/(x^2-x^3))_{(x)}=( \mathbb C[x]/(x^2(1-x)))_{(x)}=(\mathbb C[x]/(x^2))_{(x)}=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$

And thus the requested intersection number is $i(C_1,C_2;P_1)=2$.

Comment: Why is $(\mathbb C[x,y]/(y-x^2,y-x^3))_{(x,y)}=( \mathbb C[x]/(x^2-x^3))_{(x)}$? I'm guessing that the ideals $(y-x ^2,y-x^3)$ and $(y,x^2-x^3)$ are equal?

Comment: You have to send $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto x^2$ then pass to quotient then localize. One should get used to check these isomorphisms by oneself: they are practically never explicitly displayed in books.

Comment: That's probably the reason why I'll never get it.

Comment: Oh, don't say that dear Marra. Try to see as a first step that there is a surjective ring isomorphism $\mathbb C[x,y]\to \mathbb C[x]$ sending $x\mapsto x, y\mapsto x^2$ and that it sends the ideal $(y-x^2,y-x^3)$ to $(x^2-x^3)$ and then that it passes to the quotient thanks to Noether's theorem. If you are really stuck,  post a new question. Also,  you should perhaps pause to review some algebra revolving on quotient rings and Noether's isomorphisms for a few days before going on with algebraic geometry.

Comment: I just don't see why you are choosing this particular ring isomorphism (did you mean surjective ring morphism?). Is it because of the first ideal $(y-x^2)$? Then could it be, and would it work, if the morphism were $x\rightarrow x^3$?

Comment: It actually could, the result would be the same...

Comment: Yes it is because $y-x^2$ is in the denominator . You could also for the same reason send $y$ to $x^3$, obtaining a new isomorphism, but certainly not do both simultaneously: you may not send  $x$ to $x^3$. I think we should stop this exchange now, but feel free to ask a new question on the site.

Comment: I meant $y\rightarrow x^3$, sorry for that. I'll start another question after I work a little more on this one, thanks :)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You may perhaps be able to help [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/993636/29335) where someone is asking a question about a step in the solution. Regards