# Why are these two quotients equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I'm not being able to check why are these two quotients equal.

$\mathbb C[x]/(x^2-x^3)= \mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$

Can someone tell me why is it valid?

Comment: Why do you think they're equal? One has dimension 3 as a complex vector space, the other has dimension 2.

Comment: My doubt came from the answer on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991114/computing-these-multiplicities Perhaps I should localize them on $(x)$?

Comment: @AlexR: They question (apart from the title) seems to be talking about _quotients by_ ideals. However, since the quotients are different, the ideals themselves are clearly also different.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
A multiplicative Ideal generated by a Polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb C[x]$ is the set given by
$$(p) = \{ f\in \mathbb C[x] : f(x) = 0 \Leftarrow p(x) = 0\}$$
Can you find a polynomial $f$ such that $f\in (x^2) \setminus (x^2-x^3)$? (Look at the factorings)

If $(p)\ne(q)$ then $\mathbb C[x]/(p) \ne \mathbb C[x]/(q)$.

Comment: Any $a\in\mathbb{C}$ surely is. That is also true for any polynomial of degree 1. But there are also in the second one.
What about $f=x^2$? it's not on the ideal $(x^2-x^3)$ since $x^2-x^3=x^2(1-x)$. I guess.

Comment: $a\in \mathbb C$ is in no ideal if $a\ne 0$. $x^2$ serves as a counter-example. More specifically any polynomial $p$ with $p(0) = 0 \ne p(1)$ suffices.

Comment: So they are not equal. Thanks :)

Comment: Would the downvoter explain his concerns to me?